# Is there a way to enforce a minimum string length with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, validation, fluent-nhibernate

I have a string property on an entity that I would like to mark as required. For example,

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my mappings, I can declare `Name` as required (using Fluent NHibernate):

```
mapping.Map(x => x.Name).Required();
```

However, this only restricts the string from being `null`. If I assign it to `String.Empty`, NHibernate will happily store the value of `""` into the database.

My question is, is there a way of enforcing a **minimum** length for strings? For example, in this case, a product name should be at least 3 characters. Or will my business logic need to handle this instead of NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [**NHibernate validator**](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx):

```
public class Product
{
    [Length(Min=3,Max=255,Message="Oh noes!")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Marked as the answer for `Oh noes!` :).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only enforce the maximum length and nullability with NHibernate (with or without Fluent).

The minimum length can be enforced with a custom DataAnnotation at your model (or ViewModel if you use MVC and don't want to bloat your domain model with attributes)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the responsibility of (Fluent)NHibernate, it's the responsibility of a validation library. For example, check out [NHibernate Validator](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx).